# Wificonfiguration is deprecated Android 10

Tags: ftp, android-wifi, wifimanager, data-sharing, wifi

**Wifi configuration** is **deprecated** at **29 Android Version**. I want to share the file using WIFI but there is no such library which i can use for this purpose. *So If Anybody has a solution for this problem kindly share it*.

```
WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration(); 
wc.SSID = "\"SSID_NAME\""; //IMP! This should be in Quotes!!
wc.hiddenSSID = true;
boolean res1 = wifiManag.setWifiEnabled(true);
int res = wifi.addNetwork(wc);
Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res );
boolean es = wifi.saveConfiguration();
Log.d("WifiPreference", "saveConfiguration returned " + es );
boolean b = wifi.enableNetwork(res, true);
```

Is there any alternative for WifiConfiguration which i can use it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WifiConfiguration was deprecated in API level 29. Now, WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder solve my problem.

```
WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
            .setSsid(ssid)
            .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
            .build();
NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            .setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier)
            .build();
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback());
```

Comment: The WifiNetworkSpecifier works for peer to peer connections and disconnects after the operation you binded to the process gets done.